# Price Set / Pledge Conflict on WordPress

Tags: civicontribute, civipledge

I am running into an interesting issue, both on my local WordPress install and on the CiviCRM WordPress demo.

I have created a price set for contributions, and then I created a contribution page. On that page, after selecting my payment processor and price set, I am unable to get the pledge settings to save. I can check the "Pledges" box, and enter the relevant settings, (ie. selected pledge frequencies, and reminder email settings), but those settings are lost every time I click save.

I've checked to ensure that it is not an issue with my payment processor, and I have narrowed it down to the use of a price set versus the fixed contribution settings.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and does anyone have any advice? I would like to be able to use the price set, but it seems like for the immediate future, entering my donation prices directly into the form for the contribution page seems the most practical way forward. (**as a side note, I can use price sets on contribution pages without allowing pledges with no issues.) If I go with the static fixed contribution settings, what kind of flexibility am I giving up?

Comment: I've discovered a similar problem in Joomla (3.6.5), but I'm not finding answers to that either.